# Can we have a way of awarding points for a good/great edit

Tags: feature-request, editing, reputation

Currently I cannot see a way for the original poster of a Question or Answer to award points for the user that performs a very good/great edit. Users can get points for contributing via comments but not via edits.

As an example one of my answers, [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27639/software-for-a-personal-wiki-with-good-latex-support/27662#27662), had a point where I specifically admitted that I did not have & could not find the information - another user *as it happens one with a low reputation* suggested an edit which was approved by reviewers that removed my admission of ignorance and provided the information and link.

I personally think that such behaviour should be rewarded in reputation through some mechanism - possibly the reviewers and the poster of the edit flagging it as a high quality *rather than just acceptable* edit that significantly enhances the question or answer.

Does anybody agree with me?

### UPDATE

This question was first moved to the main meta and then closed there as a duplicate of [Let me reward a good edit on my question/answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36574/let-me-reward-a-good-edit-on-my-question-answer).

Comment: Similar request on the main meta: [Awarding a bounty to an editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89387/awarding-a-bounty-to-an-editor)

Comment: @giles I wasn't thinking of bounties just of a this is a more than just acceptable edit it is a positive contribution as we have for comments with the up vote button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do agree with you

I think users should be able to award points to edits that are above and beyond other edits that are just grammar, spelling, and/or formatting improvements. I believe having a feature such as this will create an environment where users will be more likely to contribute quality information that can improve a post.

I think this question; though, should be asked on [StackExchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) as a [feature-request](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request).